# How to call the server side method in office 365 .js files

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, office365

I am playing with office 365 API apps and where can i find the documentation for office api like, to select a particular row(s) and cell(s) value(s) / to select a particular sheet from all the sheets pragmatically in .js file.

I am using following code to call inside a function

`ServerClass` is the class present in `ServerClass.cs` file `Call` is the function name

```
$.ajax({
            url: "ServerClass/Call", success: function () {
                debugger;
            }
        });

public class ServerClass
    {
        [WebMethod] 
        public static void Call()
        { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is reference msdn link for JavaScript Office API, on which you will get all the required details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx

Hope this will help you.